# Can multiprocessing decrease latency of a sqlalchemy writing to server

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, parallel-processing

I have a sqlalchemy session, and want to input a 300k row 24 col (~300MB) of data

```
database_con = f'mssql://@{server}/{database}?driver={driver}'

engine = create_engine(database_con)
con = engine.connect()

df.to_sql(
            name="data",
            con=con,
            if_exists="append",
            index=False
        )
    con.commit()
```

I find that is is rather slow.

Is it possible to set up a multithreading/parallel processing session to improve the write time to the db? If so, how about would I go to set this up?

Comment: How is the title of your question even remotely accurate?

Comment: Try `engine = create_engine(database_con, fast_executemany=True)` and see if that helps.

Comment: In general, multiprocessing will do more harm than good. Contention between additional clients makes more work for the database server, it doesn't let it finish its work faster -- also, multiprocessing _in particular_ adds a bunch of inter-process communication overhead that you wouldn't have if you chose multithreading instead (as the GIL isn't held during I/O wait, which is pretty much the entirety of the time waiting for a database server to do something, multiprocessing buys you no benefit over threading in this case)

Comment: ...but again, to emphasize, _threading won't help either_; you need to focus on making your requests something the database server can process more efficiently, not on throwing more requests at it in the same amount of time. The suggestion from @GordThompson is thus directly on-point.